# How to use so-linger to keep server connection for some time

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I have TCP gateway built using Spring Integration. My server is able to process the request from the client and send response. But Client is giving `SocketException`

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:107)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:93)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:151)
```

It seems server is closing the connection before the client reads all the data. Hence I would like to use `so-linger`.

`setSoLinger` is supposed to keep the server socket open for the linger time. javadoc for `setSoLinger` says Enable/disable `SO_LINGER` with the specified linger time in seconds.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger%28boolean,%20int%29

See [Spring Integration document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html) for setting `SoLinger`.

My spring context.xml :

```
    <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
            type="server"
            port="${availableServerSocket}"
            single-use="true"
            so-timeout="10000"
            using-nio="false" 
            serializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
            deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
            so-linger="2000"/>

        <bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer"/>

        <int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
            connection-factory="crLfServer"
            request-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
            error-channel="errorChannel"
            reply-timeout="10000"/> <!-- reply-timeout works on inbound-gateway -->

        <int:channel id="toSA" />

        <int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
            ref="myService"
            method="prepare"/>

        <int:object-to-string-transformer id="serverBytes2String"
            input-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
            output-channel="toSA"/>

        <int:transformer id="errorHandler"
            input-channel="errorChannel"
            expression="payload.failedMessage.payload + ':' + payload.cause.message"/>
```

I am not sure whether Spring integration takes linger time in seconds or milli seconds. is there any other flag to be set so that Server socket is kept open till the client reads data.

I am seeing Socket connection closed event almost immediately sending response from the service bean. Server does not seem to wait. Please help how to set so-linger time or suggest alternative. Thank you.

Here is the log:

```
2016-06-01 15:43:46,276 MyService response:                 ACCEPT:E211001:

2016-06-01 15:43:46.293 DEBUG [pool-1-thread-2][org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext] Publishing event in org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@7a187814: TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection@4c4b11e9], [factory=crLfServer, connectionId=22.220.220.222:1034:5678:77483643-2156-427f-96dd-a513670a75a3] **CLOSED**

2016-06-01 15:43:46.294 DEBUG [pool-1-thread-2][org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext] Publishing event in org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext@7a187814: TcpConnectionExceptionEvent [source=org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection@4c4b11e9, cause=java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed], [factory=crLfServer, connectionId=22.220.220.222:1034:5678:77483643-2156-427f-96dd-a513670a75a3]
```

Comment: M-m-m. Can't your problem be that the `connectionSerializeDeserialize` is unable to serialize the response message? That is a case when `TcpNetConnection` close the socket on send.

Comment: yes. Its my problem. My client is trying to read data even after receiving ETX and hence the exception is thrown.Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, Gary's answer is correct and you really should revise your `single-use="true"`

Comment: '`setSoLinger()` is supposed to keep the server socket open for the linger time.' No it isn't. It is supposed to keep the closing thread blocked for up to the linger time while pending data is flushed. If you set it to zero it causes a connection reset, which you don't want either. There is rarely if ever any need to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring integration performs no conversion on the value, so it's seconds.

The behavior you describe sounds like `so-linger` is 0 (immediate RST sent for close()).

You really don't need so linger for this purpose; when it's not set the TCP stack should gracefully close the socket.

You probably need to run a network monitor to figure out what's happening.

If you trust your client to close the socket, you could remove the

`single-use="true"`

or set it to false so the server doesn't close the socket after sending the reply.

Comment: yes. Its my problem. My client is trying to read data even after receiving ETX and hence the exception is thrown. I removed so-linger so that TCP stack can close the socket. Your suggestions made server better. Thanks for your help.